# Nuxt 3 : Cannot find module '.output/server/node_modules/pinia-orm/dist/decorators' on nuxt start

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, nuxtjs3, pinia

I've got a Nuxt 3 project, with [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) and [pinia-orm](https://pinia-orm.codedredd.de/). SSR is on.

When I run the dev server with `nuxt dev`, everything runs fine.

But **if I build and start the server** with `nuxt build` and `nuxt start`, as soon as a page is requested, the server throws an error 500 and logs the following :

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot find module '/home/workspace/.output/server/node_modules/pinia-orm/dist/decorators' imported from /home/workspace/.output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs
  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)  
  at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:323:11)  
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:916:10)  
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)  
  at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)  
  at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:837:30)  
  at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)  
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)  
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)
```

I've tried to :

- remove all caches and nuxt generated files to rebuild from scratch
- move the @pinia/nuxt and @pinia-orm/nuxt dependencies in the devDependencies in package.json, as suggested [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14804#issuecomment-1397366171), even if documentations instruct otherwise
- install both pinia and and @pinia/nuxt, or only @pinia/nuxt as suggested here
- use npm and force install pinia with npm as proposed [here](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1542#issuecomment-1238820465) (I use yarn in this project)
- remove the autoImports section in the nuxt.config.ts, as suggested somewhere

Node.js is in version 18.10.0

Nuxt 3.3.3 run with [Nitro](https://nitro.unjs.io/) 2.3.2 and [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) v4.2.1

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@pinia-orm/nuxt": "^1.1.7",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "0.4.7",
    ...
    "nuxt": "^3.3.2",
    "pinia-orm": "^1.5.1",
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
}
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,
    ...
    modules: [
        ...
        [
            '@pinia/nuxt',
            {
                autoImports: [
                    // automatically imports `usePinia()`
                    'defineStore',
                    // automatically imports `usePinia()` as `usePiniaStore()`
                    ['defineStore', 'definePiniaStore'],
                ],
            }
        ],
        '@pinia-orm/nuxt',
    ],
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution (until the bug is fixed) is to add `pinia` and `pinia-orm` to the `build.transpile` array :

```
  export default defineNuxtConfig({
    // ...
+   build: {
+     transpile: ['pinia', 'pinia-orm']
+   },
    // ...
  })
```

For more infos : https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20128